# DO VPS CRON issue, not proccessing

Tags: cron, apache

I've had issues with CRON before and I usually get it fixed by following the typical troubleshooting techniques.

Setup: LAMP
OS: Ubuntu
Cron: Enabled with the following line: */5 * * * * wget -q http://exampledomain.com/cron.php

When I query the table I get the following results and running the CRON job manually isn't working.

```
select message_id, entity_type, created_at, processed_at from core_email_queue;
+------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
| message_id | entity_type | created_at          | processed_at |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
|          1 | order       | 2015-11-15 20:28:02 | NULL         |
|          2 | order       | 2015-11-15 21:15:02 | NULL         |
|          3 | order       | 2015-11-15 22:00:37 | NULL         |
|          4 | order       | 2015-11-15 22:18:08 | NULL         |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: you must call **cron.sh**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we IP protect the Magento Cron?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90150/can-we-ip-protect-the-magento-cron)

Comment: I've tried cron.sh too no luck.