# Can we IP protect the Magento Cron?

Tags: cron, security, folder

Is it ideal to IP protect the Magento cron.php? instead of folder protecting it (as referred in the http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/secy/secy-cron.html) because we want to harden the Magento security as best possible way.

FYI: I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs you linked are for Magento 2.

It is *ideal* to not allow any access to cron.php via HTTP, as it is the default since [Magento 1.9.2.2](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess#L213-L234), and execute it only via CLI and system crontab.

If for some reason you cannot to that, an IP whitelist is a valid alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The SUPEE-6788 and Magento 1.9.2.2 both updated `.htaccess` to control access to cron.php by both default denying access and giving a recommendation on how to set up password access.

```
###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php

<Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

    #AuthName "Cron auth"
    #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
    #AuthType basic
    #Require valid-user

############################################

    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all

</Files>
```

Additionally, you can add an ip address whitelist as follows (example by CIDR or single address):

```
###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php

<Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

    #AuthName "Cron auth"
    #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
    #AuthType basic
    #Require valid-user

############################################

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
    Allow from 10.2.0.15
    Deny from all

</Files>
```

For non-apache servers you will have to duplicate the rules in your server of choice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ideal to IP protect the Magento cron.php?

No. You shouldn't ever be executing `cron.php` directly, whether by CLI or HTTP.

The change Magento made in 6788 is as much a bug fix as it is a security fix. The security hole it plugged had the byproduct of forcing those who incorrectly set up their cron to properly re-implement it.

You should only ever execute `cron.sh`, so that you have job control, control over what environment the cron is run within and for security.

**Under no circumstance should `cron.php` ever be accessed directly.**